# Remote Debugging In Visual Studio 2013 Doesn't Target Remote Machine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I have a strange issue in VS2013 that's driving me crazy.  I'm trying to deploy a Windows Store App to a surface rt device via remote debugging tools. This has always worked perfectly but now when I select "Remote Machine" and hit Start Debugging, Start Without Debugging or Deploy, the app always opens up on the local machine.  If I blank out the Surface RT devices name from the projects Properties->Debug->Remote Machine menu then I get an error

"A machine name must be entered in the project properties page to debug the application remotely.  Would you like to specify a remote machine name now?"

But as soon as I enter the correct name, the app launches, but on the local machine.

Is there a log that can show me what is going on?  Nothing happens on the Remote Surface RT device inside the Remote Debugging Monitor.

UPDATE: Remote Debugging seems to work fine if I target another windows 8.1 machine.  It's just the Surface RT device that doesn't seem to work. This would lead me to believe it's something to do with ARM.  The project is however set to build as "Any CPU" which it always has been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that despite when browsing the remote machine it clearly knew what port number it was running on, I had to type :PORT_NUMBER after the remote machines name to get it to work.